# the jquery form is not working correctly, I keep getting double emails at a time

Tags: php, jquery

I keep getting two emails when i sent the form, also it keep getting " Error when sending the message"  even after I send and receive the email.. I would also like to display the error message if the fields are empty

```
<?php
#if you also need this script to respond to other domains, add those header lines
// header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
// header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
// header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
if($_POST) {
    $userEmail=$_POST['userEmail'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    //$destEmail=$_POST['destEmail'];
    $body=$_POST['textarea'];

    $response = mail("email@yahoo.com", $subject, $body, "From:" . $userEmail);
    echo $response;
    exit();
}
?>


    <form >

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input name="subject" id="Subject_input" value="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div data-role="fieldcontain">
       <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" id="Email_input" value="" type="email">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="textarea">
        Qusstions/Feedback:
        </label>
    <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="MessageText_input"></textarea>
         </div>
         <input type="button" id="sendlink" class="reset" value="submit contact"/>

          </form>


    <script>

             $('#sendlink').on("vclick", function(e) {
                 "use strict";
                e.preventDefault();
                var data={
                        userEmail: $('#Email_input').val(),
                        subject: $('#Subject_input').val(),
                        textarea: $('#MessageText_input').val()          
                       };
                function sendToServer() {
                    return $.ajax({
                        url: 'yates-contact-form-app.php',
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        data: data
                    });
                }

                //sendToServer().done(handleSuccess);
                //sendToServer().fail(handleError);
                sendToServer().done(function() {
                     alert("Message successfully sent");
       $(".reset").closest('form').find("input[type=text],input[type=email],textarea").val("");
                   $.mobile.navigate("#benefits-facts");

                });
               sendToServer().fail(function() {
                     alert(" Error when sending the message");

                    /*console.log("Error when sending the message : ");
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data.response);
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log(jqXHR);*/
                });
            });
             </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling sendToServer 2 times, 1 for the done handler another for the fail handler so you are getting the mail 2 times.

Instead you need to register both these handlers to the same promise like

```
$('#sendlink').on("vclick", function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        userEmail: $('#Email_input').val(),
        subject: $('#Subject_input').val(),
        textarea: $('#MessageText_input').val()
    };

    //validation
    if (!data.userEmail || !data.subject || !data.textarea) {
        alert('enter the data!!!')
        return;
    }

    function sendToServer() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'yates-contact-form-app.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: data
        });
    }

    var req = sendToServer();
    req.done(function () {
        //do your stuff
    });
    req.fail(function () {
        //do your stuff
    });

    //or you can just chain both these calls
});
```

Comment: can you add an `alert()` in the `sendToServer` method and see how many times it is getting called

Comment: if i use       var req = sendToServer();  I get      alert(" Error when sending the message");

Comment: I get only one alert if I do this:  function sendToServer() {
  alert("send to server");
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'yates-contact-form-app.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: data
        });
  
    }

Comment: I only get one "sending" alert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82789/discussion-between-brodster-and-arun-p-johny).